# R: loop matrix sort columns individually for specific rows

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I want to sort my Matrix (U) columnwise for the rows, which have the same name. My (very large) matrix looks similar to this:

```
  1  2 
1 5  6
1 -4 4
1 6 -2
2 7 -2
2 -2 3
```

Now I want to loop through the matrix looking for the same rows and then sort the columns which have the same row.name resulting in this matrix:

```
   1   2 
1 -4   -2
1  5   4
1  6   6
2  -2  -2
2  7   3
```

My code until now looks like this:

First step was the row count, which works:

```
z <- 1 
for(i in (1:nrow(U))){
 if(row.names(U)[i] != row.names(U)[i-1]){
 z = (sum(row.names(U) == row.names(U)[i]))+1}}
```

Now I wanted to add after the row count a sorting function and I tried this for the first set of rows manually:

```
x <- 1
for(x in (1:ncol(U))){
  U[1:3,x]<- U[do.call(order, lapply(x:NCOL(U), function(x) U[1:3, x]
```

However this loop is on the one hand very slow and on the other hand it only fills in the first column correctly

Do you have a recommendation how I could improve my sorting function, while taking into account the performance issues?

EDIT: I guess this was confusing in my first edit. The first "column" of my matrix are the row.names and I have in this example a 5x2 Matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach which just uses order() first by row name, then by each column in turn. Is this what you're after?

```
U <- matrix(c(5,6,-4,4,6,-2,7,-2,-2,3), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2, dimnames=list(c(1,1,1,2,2), c(1,2)))

apply(U, 2, function(j) j[order(rownames(U), j)])
```

Comment: Your apply function does exactly what I was after. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`, convert to `data.table`, grouped by the first column ('U'), loop through the columns and `sort`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(m1)[, lapply(.SD, sort), by = U]
```

Comment: I guess, I got your point and now I think it works: `as.data.table(U)[, lapply(.SD, sort), by = list(row.names(U)) ]`

Comment: @Max I thought 'U' is your first column and not row names

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `dplyr`

```
df = read.table(textConnection("U 1  2 
1 5  6
1 -4 4
1 6 -2
2 7 -2
2 -2 3"), header= TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(U) %>% transmute(sort(X1),sort(X2))
```